# Ionic not posting

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I've created an API which the variables post fine to when I use postmaster however the variables are empty on the backend when I send through ionic

```
var details = {"v1" : $scope.loginData.v1, "v2": $scope.loginData.v2};
$http.post(api, details, {
   headers : {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
}
```

I have checked the values of $scope.loginData.v1 print out fine on the front end.

Comment: are you sure you aren't getting an error, like CORS for example?

Comment: Thanks for answer I have checked this and I am not getting any JS errors at all.